# Library Java can't resolve in Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I really need help because I try search other forum and other problem same answer regarding to javax.imageio.ImageIO and java.awt.image.BufferedImage cannot be resolved in android studio 3.1. Suggestion say that I have to use alternative function but I couldn't find it. The function that I need is that

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file)
```

Full code below here;

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        File auxFile = new File(selectedImage.toString());

        try {
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(auxFile);
            LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bufferedImage);
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
            Result resultTxt = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);

            Toast.makeText(this, "result:"+resultTxt.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }catch (IOException e){

        }catch (NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I really appreciated those who can help me.

Comment: why down vote my question?it is really problem that need to ask follow the guide to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The packages javax.imageio.ImageIO and java.awt.image.BufferedImage are not available on android.You should use Bitmaps instead.
To read a bitmap from a file you should do this instead.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
```

Comment: hai thanks for reply. Actually from zxing library they use this after those code LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bufferedImage);
                BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
                Result resultTxt = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);

Comment: so where can I get buffered Image instead of bitmap. The reason behind this this library scan file image qr code instead of scan image from camera. Any further explain I really appreciated

Comment: By the way, library zxing decode binary bitmap instead of bitmap

Comment: Zxing library for android uses bitmaps, you're using the Java SE package. https://github.com/zxing/zxing/

Comment: my answer to my question can refer to here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199282/library-zxing-cannot-use-in-android-3-1). I couldn't answer my question and I do not know why