# Android - javax.imageio does not exists

Tags: android, javax.imageio, jmonkeyengine

One of the libs in my Android project (jMonkey 3 based) uses javax.imageio which does not exist in Android SDK.

Is there anything to do about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ IDEA import javax.imageio.ImageIO package does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297296/intellij-idea-import-javax-imageio-imageio-package-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0):

There is a download available for `javax.imageio` at https://jar-download.com/download-handling.php

See if adding this jar as dependency work for you.

Here are its documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html

**NOTE:** If you can change the library then you should try to use remove `imageio` and use `Bitmap` instead; if possible.

Comment: Even if you somehow managed to make the import work, it would blow up at runtime. ImageIO can't be used on Android, as it is dependent on Java2D.